# Sum of the digits of $2001^{10}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

I saw this question in internet and I could not solve it.
I saw that many people are trying to solve these kind of questions by Python. Then I decided that this question is a computer-science kind of question.
If a program is solving my problem, where is the fun and pride on this?

My try: Since $2001^{10}\equiv0 \pmod{9}$, the sum of the digits $SD$ is a multiple of $9$. Also, this number contains $34$ digits. So, $SD\leq9\times34=306$. I thought about the binomial expansion $(2000+1)^{10}$ but it is complicated.

The answer is $108$. How can I find it without calculator? Is there a method? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I will write ten numbers the first one being 10240000...0 and then add these numbers? I am calculating the number not its sum of the digits.

Comment: PARI/GP is much easier to use. I would suggest this for problems like that.

Comment: Last 3 digits are $001$ and first digit is $1$, which gives a little better approximation $SD \leq 9\times 30 + 2 = 272$, but that's still far from result.

Comment: You can also consider mod 11. $2001\equiv 3\pmod {11}$, so $2001^{10}\equiv 3^{10}\equiv 1\pmod{11}$

Comment: @ajotatxe $2001$ is congruent to $-1$ modulo $11$ and not $3$ ($2002$ is divisible by $11$), but that doesn't change the fact that $2001^{10} \equiv 1 \mod 11$ at least.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer;

On rewriting it as $(2000+1)^{10}$, we can apply binomial expansion on this as follows,

$$(2000+1)^{10}=\sum_{r=0}^{10} \binom nr (2000)^r$$

$$\sum_{r=0}^{10} \binom nr (2000)^r=\binom{10}{0}+\binom{10}{1}(2000)+\binom{10}{2}(2000^2)+\binom{10}{3}(2000)^3+\binom{10}{4}(2000)^4+\binom{10}{5}(2000)^5+\binom{10}{6}(2000)^6+\binom{10}{7}(2000)^7+\binom{10}{8}(2000)^8+\binom{10}{9}(2000)^9+\binom{10}{10}(2000)^{10}$$

$$=1+10(2000)+45(2000)^2+120(2000)^3+210(2000)^4+252(2000)^5+\cdots$$

> $$=1029131535373448067360960180020001$$

The sum of digits = $1+2+9+1+3+1+5+3+5+3+7+3+4+4+8+6+7+3+6+9+6+1+8+2+1 = 108$

> Extra; for $T=(2000)^n$, for any natural
> $n>0$, the sum of digits in $T$ is essentially the sum of digits in
> $2^n$

Comment: But how did you sum it easily? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @BobDobbs evaluating $\binom {10}{r}$ is pretty easy(follows a good pattern too), and I used the part written in the extra column, honestly this is not a great answer rather it is a dumb approach (had it been any other exponent).

Answer (score -2):

The easiest and quickest is pen and paper, write down 2001, then add 2000x nine times, then count the digits.

Or start with x = 4,004,001, then add 4,000x and 4,000,000x four times, and count the digits.

Pari/GP? Seriously?